# Pinterest and bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, pinterest

So, I'm using Tabs but for some reason when I put pinterest Inside a tab content it doesn't show up.
[JsFiffle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhrb90v7/)

Outside them works fine but won't load inside the tabs.

```
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of third party JS-driven libraries, such as Google Maps, and evidently Pinterest's feed embed JS, don't work properly when initialised on a HTML container that is **hidden** when the JS library is initialised (so to put this another way, if you put the Pinterest feed in the tab that **is** active when the page loads, it should work).

I have managed to get around the issue as follows:

1. HTML Snippet

   ```
               <!-- Nav tabs -->
               <ul id="social-feed-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Instagram" aria-controls="Instagram" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Instagram</a></li>
                   <li role="presentation"><a href="#Pinterest" aria-controls="Pinterest" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="PinterestTab">Pinterest</a></li>
                   ...
               </ul>

               <!-- Tab panes -->
               <div class="tab-content">
                   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Instagram">...</div>
                   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Pinterest">
                       <a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://www.pinterest.com/username/" data-pin-scale-width="80" data-pin-scale-height="170" data-pin-board-width="360">Loading Pinterest feed...</a>
                   </div>
                   ...
               </div>
   ```
2. JS Code

   ```
   var isPinterestLoaded = false;

   function handlePinterest() {
       $('#PinterestTab').click(function () {
           loadPinterestJs();
       });

   }

   function loadPinterestJs() {
       if (!isPinterestLoaded) {
           (function (d) {
               var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
               p.type = 'text/javascript';
               p.async = true;
               p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
               f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
           }(document));
           isPinterestLoaded = true;
       }
   }

   handlePinterest(); // You may want to call this on the document.ready event, or similar, depending on your setup.
   ```